# Change javascript variable in seperate element

Tags: javascript, html, class, variables, element

I run a WoW guild forum based on php (phpbb), javascript and html. Ever since long, Wowhead allows links to be posted to their item/spell IDs etc. The basic code to the Wowhead JS and it's variables is:

```
<script src="//static.wowhead.com/widgets/power.js"></script>
<script>var wowhead_tooltips = { "colorlinks": true, "iconizelinks": true, "renamelinks": true }</script>
```

There is an extension that puts this code in the footer of every page via a HTML file. Every Wowhead link posted will be converted in a link with a tooltip explaining what it links to. The '"renamelink": true' portion of the wowhead_tooltips variable makes it as such that any link of an item or spell is renamed to the exact name of what it is linked to.

The problem: when I generate custom URLs using a Wowhead link, ie:

```
<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/spell=1953">Teleport</a>
```

instead of displaying 'Teleport' with a tooltip of Blink, it will rename the entire URL to Blink with an icon, as described in the wowhead_tooltips variable.

What I want to achieve is:

1. Any direct URL to Wowhead should be converted into a renamed spell/item.
2. Any custom URL to Wowhead should be retain it's custom text, but retrieve the tooltip.
3. This should both be possible on a single page.

The best solution I have come up with is to add an 'if' function to var wowhead_tooltips based on class, then add the class to URLs:

```
<script>if ($('a').hasClass("wowrename")) { var wowhead_tooltips = { "colorlinks": true, "iconizelinks": true, "renamelinks": false } }</script>
<a class="wowrename" href="http://www.wowhead.com/spell=1953">Teleport</a>
```

This works, however, the problem with this solution is that once the script recognizes one URL with the class "wowrename" on the page it will stop renaming all links, meaning that custom URLs and direct URLs can't be mixed on a single page.

Any other solution I've tried, using IDs, defining different variables etc either don't work or come up with the same restriction.

Hence the question, is it possible to change Javascript variables (in this case "var wowhead_tooltips { "renamelinks": false}" per element (URL), based on id, class or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct link that gets renamed with tooltip and iccn.

```
<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/spell=1953">Teleport</a>
```

Custom link with tooltip and original text.
I've stored the original link text as a data attribute so we can restore it after it's been changed.

```
<a class="wowrename" href="http://www.wowhead.com/spell=1953" data-value="Teleport">Teleport</a>
```

Keep checking for when `static.wowhead.com/widgets/power.js` changes the last link text. Once changed, restore using the `data-value` value, remove the styling added that creates the icon and stop the timer.

```
$(function () {
    //timmer
    checkChanged = setInterval(function () {
        // check for when the last link text has changed
        var lastItem = $("a.wowrenameoff").last();
        if (lastItem.text() !== lastItem.data('value')) {
            $("a.wowrenameoff").each(function () {
                //change value
                $(this).text($(this).data('value'));
                //remove icon
                $(this).attr('style', '');

                //stop timer
                clearInterval(checkChanged);
            });
        }

        i++;
    }, 100);
});
```

This does cause the link icon to flicker on then off, but it is repeated after a page refresh.

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n7v0brxs/2/)

Comment: Yes, that's it! I have to be very honest I do really understand what's going on with this change but it works, I would like to understand though: if I grasp it correctly, you let the script run that does not recognize a direct link due to data-href, then change data-href to href so that the link remains but does not get renamed?

Comment: I'm noticing a small issue with this fix: initially it works fine, but when I reload the page it will rename any custom URLs anyway. It reinstates itself when I navigate away from the page and go back directly. This is a minor issue, but is there a fix?

Comment: I've updated my answer to help with the reload issue. Hopefully it is better explained too. If not just ask again.

Comment: I see what you mean with the icon flash, but that's not an issue. Thanks much again! I'm grasping the concept of what it's doing. If it's okay with you I think I'll direct the author of the extension (phpbb's Gametooltips, author PayBas) to this answer whether he wants to include a variation in the phpbb extension. For those also interested for phpbb: I've added my own bbCode: `BBCode: [wow={TEXT1}]{TEXT2}[/wow] HTML: <a class="wowrenameoff" href="http://www.wowhead.com/{TEXT1}" data-value="{TEXT2}">{TEXT2}</a>`

Comment: Slight addition: the BBCode HTML contains the class "wowrenameoff"; I renamed the class as I thought it was more logical because it prevents renaming. In order for it to work, either the class in the script has to be renamed to "wowrenameoff" (a.wowrenameoff) or the class in the BBCode to "wowrename".

Comment: It's still not 100% working for the intention I wanted to use it for. This is the link to my test page: [link](http://www.wow-scum.com/page/test), which parses BBCodes (the code I've made above). If I copy the same BBCode multiple times it seems to work, but when I use different ones, in a list etc, it seems to rename some of the links anyway (mostly later on the page/post). Any thoughts?

Comment: It's because the timer comes in before the `power.js` has finished. For now just change `100` to say `5000`. I'm looking to a better way of checking when it's compete before we run the function.

Comment: Updated my answer and added the test page content to the JSFiddle.

Comment: I notice that it now renames links and then undos the rename: with the timer on 100 it would still occasionally load a link after your script ran, still renamed. I currently have it on 500 (leading to a minor delay on posts with custom wowhead links) and it's working fine on the post with hunter pet buffs. It's fine for me now, thanks again. If you (or anyone else) have any additional suggestions be my guest.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop on all the links, like this:

```
$("a.wowrename").each(function() {
    // some code
});
```

Comment: I tried this adding: `code`var wowhead_tooltips = { "colorlinks": true, "iconizelinks": true, "renamelinks": false } but it does not seem to work... seems to be what I'm looking for though, not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: What code you suggest to be inside the loop? It's no sense to change `wowhead_variable` inside this loop. The result will be -> property `wowhead_tooltips.renamelinks` will be `true` the behavior of all links will be `renamelinks`

Answer (score 0):

This is simple solution. It's not the best way.

```
var wowhead_tooltips = { "colorlinks": true, "iconizelinks": true, "renamelinks": true }
$('a').hover(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('wowrename') {
    wowhead_tooltips.renamelinks = true;
  }
  else {
    wowhead_tooltips.renamelinks = false;
  }
});
```

I don't know how exactly wowhead API works, but if wowhead_tooltips variable is loaded exactly in the moment when the user points the link with the mouse (without any timeout) - this can fail or randomly work/not work.
The reason can be that the javascript don't know which function to execute first.

I hope this will work. If it's not - comment I will think for another way.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. I think that essentially this is not the fix I am looking for, as this only changes the script based on whether the link is being hovered over, if I understand it correctly. I would like it to be if the page is loaded.

Comment: Actually the `wowhead_tooltips` variable is used for all links. you can see that `wowhead_tooltip.renamelinks` is in plural. I will look for something that can set the `renamelins` functionality at specific link only.